# Find item between row and column in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows

I want to find what's the position of the following array, according to the table below.

So, here is an example:

I have this array : ['AA','CC','TC']

and I have this table:

[image]

Now, according to the array, my first value is 'AA'. So if you notice, we have A and A as the fist index, which we have to read in the table below. So first, we look in the rows of the table, and then we check the columns. we see, that the number of the row and of the columns in the value:12.

So far I have this code in JavaScript:

```
function cal_extinction_coefficient(str) {

var values_compare= [['Values', 'A','C','T'], ['A', 12,14,16], ['C',23,25,26],  ['T',31,34,37]];

var values_to_find=['AA','CC','TC']

let chunk=0;
var all_combLength= values_to_find.length;
for (var i = 0; i < all_combLength; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < values_compare.length; j++) {
         const final= times[j].includes(all_combinations[i].slice(0,1));
         
    }

    
}
```

However, I don't know how to access these values... I have the same resolution, but in pandas and with python...
Can someone help me please?

Comment: add your JavaScript code with given input

Comment: You could use nested objects: `const type1 = {A: {A: 27, C: 21}, C: {A: 21, C: 14}}` and access your elements with `type1['A']['C']` or `type1.A.C`

Comment: Using [lodash#get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) you can access the element with `_.get(type1, ['A', 'C'])`.

Comment: What does *"item between row and column"* mean?

Comment: Is like the naval battle, Depending on the specific row and column, I chose the number beteween them

Comment: So... the value at the position where a particular row intersects a particular column? Wouldn't that just be indexing into a 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to JS, try to create your own functions first. It's usually easier than it seems to be.

```js
const data = {
  dataFrame: [
    ['A', 27, 21],
    ['C', 21, 14]
  ],
  columns: ['Type', 'A','C']
}

const getValue = (xy) => {
  [col, row] = xy.split('');
  return data.dataFrame.find(x => x[0] == row)?.[data.columns.indexOf(col)];
}

console.log(getValue("AA"));
```

Comment: I edited the description, so that you could understand it better, thank you so much

Comment: I really didn't understand what you want to do. It's a very unclear description. I updated my answer based on your new parameters, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested objects:

```
const type1 = {A: {A: 27, C: 21}, C: {A: 21, C: 14}}
```

and access your elements with

```
type1['A']['C']
```

or

```
type1.A.C
```

Using [lodash#get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) you can access the element with

```
_.get(type1, ['A', 'C'])
```

Examples:

```js
const type1 = {A: {A: 27, C: 21}, C: {A: 21, C: 14}};

console.log(type1['A']['C']);

console.log(type1.A.C);

console.log(_.get(type1, ['A', 'C']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```